# ASP.net check if page is http or https

Tags: asp.net, https

I have a web application hosted on multiple servers some of which are on https. How can I check from code behind if a page is currently in http or https?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You can refer to the `Request.IsSecureConnection` property on the `HttpRequest` class. For a full reference outside a page, user control or alike, use `HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection`.

Comment: Beware- IsSecureConnection can give false negatives. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/998397/why-does-request-issecureconnection-return-false-when-true-is-expected

Comment: Answer is little old, so now, for me it was a bit changed with owin. I got the value by "System.Web.HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Request.IsSecure". May be this comes handy for some one later. :)

Answer (score 29):

```
Page.Request.Url.Scheme
```

works as well. It returns `http`, `https`, etc.

Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.scheme.aspx

Answer (score 8):

Use - `HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection`

Answer (score 8):

Update for Aspnet Core 2.0, now, you should use `Request.IsHttps` inside your controllers.

Comment: As of NET Core 2.2 you can use ```Request.Scheme``` which should return either ```https``` or ```http```. Either work fine on Windows servers although on Ubuntu ```IsHttps``` and ```Request.Scheme``` both say the request is not secure for me so not sure if this is a bug or something configured wrongly.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively:

```
Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_PROTOCOL"];
```

Comment: This returns `HTTP/1.1` for me on both http and https while `Request.IsSecureConnection` returns as expected.

Answer (score 2):

In .net core I use:

```
Context.Request.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttps
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
aCookie.Secure = HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection
```