# Ensure page is served in HTTPS in WebMatrix

Tags: razor, https, webmatrix

How do I ensure a page in my site is ALWAYS served securely?

I've been doing some investigation, and it looks like I can use the following class:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection;
```

Firstly, is this the correct way to do it? If so, how do I use that class? do I use it to set a bool, and perform a redirect on it if that fails?

I've checked out this link, but I don't know how to convert this to be used with WebPages?

[ASP.net check if page is http or https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356389/asp-net-check-if-page-is-http-or-https)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than writing code to perform this, I would suggest using the URL Rewrite component within IIS on the server you're hosting it on (if present). URL Rewrite will be able to catch the requests and rewrite them as secure before your code ever sees the request.

If you need help setting up URL rewrite there is information at the following link, including what your `web.config` should end up looking like:

http://www.jppinto.com/2010/03/automatically-redirect-http-requests-to-https-on-iis7-using-url-rewrite-2-0/

---

To also directly answer your question, `IsSecureConnection` is a read-only bool property that tells you whether you are running on a secure connection. You can use it in any of your `.cshtml` pages from the `Request` object. Just add the following to a page to get the idea:

```
@Request.IsSecureConnection
```

To set the connection as secure you would need to redirect the user to a https connection, but as I said above I feel this is better achieved with URL Rewrite than through code (although your code can certainly ensure that it **is** on a secure connection when it expects to be and throw an error if it isn't).

Comment: Thanks dude! yeah, i managed to redirect my page using the outcome of a bool set using "IsSecureConnection" and it actually works quite well, but i can imagine it'll get quite messy. I also currently use the URLrewrite module, so it makes perfect sense to utilise that for the redirect instead, and keep my code a little cleaner. Appreciate your help (again).