# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS for all pages

Tags: c#, https, url-rewriting, web-config

If I type in example.com it redirects to https://example.com as I want to. However when typing http://example.com/blog it still redirects to https://example.com

```xml
<rewrite>
      <rules>
        <clear/>
         <rule name="Force HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

How can I make it add https to whatever the user wrote?

Comment: Did you try the code here? http://stackoverflow.com/a/47095/993547

Comment: Yes. I've added the outbound rules now and still, it redirectsto the root

Comment: please try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32523540/http-to-https-rewrite-too-many-redirect-loops-iis-7 and for in detail information ,please follow this artical http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToEnableHTTPStrictTransportSecurityHSTSInIIS7.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use attribute [System.Web.Mvc.RequireHttps] for controller.

If you need it on all controller, you can use following code (**only Asp.Net MVC6/core**).

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddMvc(options =>
    {
        options.Filters.Add(typeof(RequireHttpsInProductionAttribute));
    });
}
```

**Note:** And you can use HSTS to avoid client to use http request next time.

```
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Strict-Transport-Security" value="max-age=31536000"/>
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: the BlogController? or the Home?

Comment: @crystyxn use [RequireHttps] attribute on all the controllers you need to use https.

Comment: im using ASP.NET MVC 5

Comment: just use [RequireHttps] on all the controller. But it cann't help you for static files.