# Elastic Beanstalk redirect http to https for iis site

Tags: amazon-web-services, iis, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using Elastic Beanstalk on AWS for a .net core site hosted on IIS.

I'm unsure how to get http to redirect to https. Following this:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-httpredirect.html

I have done the first step, but unsure what to do in the second step. I'v followed the github link, but dont know what to do with the file.

https://github.com/awsdocs/elastic-beanstalk-samples/blob/master/configuration-files/aws-provided/security-configuration/https-redirect/dotnet/https-redirect-load-balanced-dotnet.config

Instructions are unclear.

I'm open to suggestions of other methods of getting http to redirect to https

Comment: use this url rewrite rule in iis: `<rule name="Rewrite HTTP to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true"><match url="^(.*)$"/> <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny"><add input="{HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO}" pattern="^http$"/></conditions><action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}"/></rule>` for more detailed information refer this link: [link1](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redirect-http-https-elb/) ,[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19791820/redirect-to-https-through-url-rewrite-in-iis-within-elastic-beanstalks-load-bal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked for me
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47806650/66975

```
<rewrite>
   <rules>
      <rule name="HTTPS Rule behind AWS Elastic Load Balancer Rule" stopProcessing="true">
         <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
         <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO}" pattern="^http$" ignoreCase="false" />
         </conditions>
         <action type="Redirect" url="https://{SERVER_NAME}{URL}" redirectType="Found" />
      </rule>
   </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Answer (score 5):

I was confused by all the documentation and answers providing code for rewrite rules, which I could never get to work. I eventually figured out how to do this via the AWS web console:

1. Make sure you are using an Application Load Balancer for your application's environment.
2. Add a listener for https, port 443, and your certificate *(AWS documentation covers this quite well)*
3. *This was the part that took me hours to figure out:*
   You **cannot** configure the redirect from Elastic Beanstalk's load balancer configuration section.  You have to go to `Services -> EC2 -> Load balancers` and then select the load balancer created for your application/environment.
   *If you have multiple load balancers, it's hard to determine which one is the correct one. I had to refer to the "Created At" timestamp to know which one to select.*
4. Click the "Listeners" tab
5. Click the View/edit rules link on the HTTP:80 listener
6. Click the + icon to add a new rule
7. Add an action of "Redirect to..." and enter 443 for the port.
   *The rest of the inputs defaulted to the correct values.*
8. Add a "Host header" condition and set the value to your host
9. Save the rule

Comment: This should be the answer for all the questions related to HTTPS redirection on Elastic Beanstalk! Thanks Mike!

Comment: This has taken me hours! Thank you so much. Is it also necessary to set a host value for both www.domain.com and domain.com (no www)? Or just one of them?