# IIS with URL Rewrite as a reverse proxy not working with Nextcloud

Tags: redirect, url-rewriting, reverse-proxy, iis-10, nextcloud

I have a server (call the main server - run Window Server 2022 and use IIS 10 for the web server -  private IP: 10.10.1.1) with the domain `tuitentuan.com`. I host some web on this server.

Today, I'm trying to create my cloud storage. I decided to use Nextcloud run on Ubuntu Server 22.04.2 (call it sub server - private IP: 10.10.1.10). It runs well on LAN.

Now, I want to public my NAT using my domain `drive.tuitentuan.com`, but I'm NAT my domain to the main server, so I can't NAT to my cloud storage. I'm tired to find some solution and found `Reverse Proxy`.

I'm trying following this guideline [IIS with URL Rewrite as a reverse proxy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/friis/setup-iis-with-url-rewrite-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-real-world-apps), but it does not work for me.

Here is my web config for web `drive.tuitentuan.com`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://10.10.1.10/{R:1}" />
                    <serverVariables>
                        <set name="HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="{HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING}" />
                        <set name="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="" />
                    </serverVariables>
                </rule>
            </rules>
            <outboundRules>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyOutboundRule1" preCondition="ResponseIsHtml1">
                    <match filterByTags="A, Form, Img" pattern="^http(s)?://10.10.1.10/(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="http{R:1}://drive.tuitentuan.com/{R:2}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="RestoreAcceptEncoding" preCondition="NeedsRestoringAcceptEncoding">
                    <match serverVariable="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" pattern="^(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="{HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_ACCEPT_ENCODING}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Rewrite uri a tag" preCondition="ResponseIsTextStar">
                    <match pattern="href=(.*?)https://10.10.1.10/(.*?)\s" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="href={R:1}https://drive.tuitentuan.com/{R:2}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Rewrite uri button tag" preCondition="ResponseIsTextStar">
                    <match pattern="action=(.*?)https://10.10.1.10/(.*?)\\" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="action={R:1}https://drive.tuitentuan.com/{R:2}\" />
                </rule>
                <preConditions>
                    <preCondition name="ResponseIsHtml1">
                        <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/(.+)" />
                    </preCondition>
                    <preCondition name="NeedsRestoringAcceptEncoding">
                        <add input="{HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_ACCEPT_ENCODING}" pattern=".+" />
                    </preCondition>
                    <preCondition name="ResponseIsTextStar">
                        <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
                    </preCondition>
                </preConditions>
            </outboundRules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

And here is my config in the hosts file (`C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`)

```
127.0.0.1   tuitentuan.com
127.0.0.1   tool.tuitentuan.com
127.0.0.1   cdn.tuitentuan.com
127.0.0.1   accounts.tuitentuan.com
127.0.0.1   drive.tuitentuan.com
```

With this config, I got an error `redirected you too many times` (you can try it to see the error at [drive.tuitentuan.com](https://drive.tuitentuan.com)).

All my server and service are running on default port (80, 443).

How do I resolve my problem?

Thank you for the time to read my post. Please ignore if there are errors in the article because of my limited understanding.

Comment: So there is only redirected too many times error? Is there a detailed error message? About this error you can refer to this discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32523540/http-to-https-rewrite-too-many-redirect-loops-iis-7. You can use FRT: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/using-failed-request-tracing-rules-to-troubleshoot-application-request-routing-arr to find out why the redirection failed.